# Should a stream server be seperate from a web server?

Tags: web-server, amazon-web-services, streaming

I'm going to be playing with Amazon's web services. I'm going to install Ubuntu 12.04 and start setting up my server stack. Once of the projects I wanted to work on involed a red5 server. My question is, Should I install the red5 server as a separate server or can I use the same web server to handle my streams?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to worry about PCI compliance, then putting the red5 server on another (virtual) machine will save you a bunch of administrative headaches.

Or, if your virtual machine can't handle the load of both servers at once, then you should separate them.

Otherwise you should be fine.